# Bash subshell very weird behavior with ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

Consider script s2:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh localhost tail
```

And script s1

```
#!/bin/bash
./s2 &
sleep 1000
wait
```

Now call s1. It won't call the ssh command.

If you remove the & in s1 it will.
If you call ./s2 directly it will.
If you type in the console ./s2 & it will.

But ./s1 won't work. Why ?

Comment: how did u check that *"It won't call the ssh command"*?

Comment: It works for me.  How do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know for me it does not call the ssh command. If i remove the sleep then it exits immediately. But it does run s2 I checked it. Then it may be system dependent which is bad....

Comment: If your `s1` script backgrounds the `tail` command run by `s2`, where do you think `tail` should get its stdin? What happens if you `ssh localhost tail -f /var/log/something` in `s2` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know for me it does not call the ssh command. If i remove the sleep then it exits immediately.

Sure it calls the `ssh` command. It has to! There's no magic.

It's a big mistake to assume that just because the script exits immediately when you remove `sleep`, it is not calling `ssh`.
That conclusion is incorrect.
There can be other reasons to explain this observed behavior.

If you wanted to verify that `ssh` did not run,
one way to do that would be to look at your system logs.

The script exits *very soon* (not immediately) because `ssh` exits very soon.
When `s2` runs, it receives empty `stdin`,
which the `tail` command consumes and outputs nothing,
and so the `ssh` shell terminates without any output. That's all.

Change `s2` to this to see the difference:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls / | ./s2 &
wait
```

This way `s2` will have a non-empty `stdin` to work with,
and should produce some output.

Btw the `sleep 1000` was unnecessary from the beginning, thanks to the `wait`.